# getting error: ninja: Error copying file build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to add all header files upon post build using add_custom_command files to libraries/include folder but it's failing giving this error. Can someone suggest the possible workaround how can I achieve same by some modifications needed. Thanks in advance.

Getting this error:

```
Error copying file 
build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

CmakeLists.txt:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

add_library(abc
        STATIC
        src/a.cpp
        src/b.cpp
        src/c.cpp
        src/d.cpp
        src/e.cpp
        src/f.cpp )

set(libraries_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../libraries)

set_target_properties(abc
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        "${libraries_DIR}/abc/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}")

FILE(GLOB files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h")

MESSAGE("FILE LIST IS: ${files}")


FOREACH(file ${files})
    add_custom_command(TARGET abc POST_BUILD
            COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E
            copy "${file}"
            "${libraries_DIR}/abc/include/"
            COMMENT "Copying abc to output directory")
ENDFOREACH()
```

Comment: By any chance, are you using gradle plugin 4.2 versions? (4.2.2 for example) If yes, then try using gradle 4.1.2, which solved a problem relative to this. I still don't know the source of the issue though. It just doesn't happen on an old version and native side builds as expected.